# 2-1 bootstrap layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

You can see what I am trying to make here. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMwKqv

I need this markup:

```
<div class="col-offset-xs-7 col-offset-s-7 col-offset-md-7 col-offset-lg-7
            col-xs-7 col-s-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 border"> 
    Google Maps to populate
</div>
```

To have a min height of 500 without pushing the row below it up so the zipcode results show up under the users. Anyone have an idea on how I could get that to look right?

Comment: i don't know if it will fix your issue, but the small class abbreviation is 'sm', not 's'.

Comment: Thank you lol. I didnt even notice

Comment: I kind of got it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WreQLG